# Outlook 2003 items stuck in outbox after sent (POP3)

Tags: pop3, outlook-2003

I have a PC, when the user sends an item it's stuck in the outbox after sending. The strange thing is that the mails are being sent to the recepient. It's just that Outlook doesn't move it from Outbox to Sent Items...I checked all the settings and all is well. This is a POP3 account.

What else can I check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to resolve the issue with the methods on [this page](http://www.howto-outlook.com/faq/messagestuckinoutbox.htm). Don't ignore the links to the relevant MS KB articles. They may be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the username in the account settings from username to username@domain.com and that fixed the problem.

Comment: Glad you resolved this issue. Please be sure to mark your answer as "accepted" when you are able.